# how to add parameters to windows 8 shortcuts

Tags: windows-8

After installing windows8.1 and firefox, it created a shortcut on the quick launch that has some extra options when you right click it, such as start in private mode, unpin from the quickstart bar, etc.

i want to add a command line parameter to the shortcut. On windows7 and before I would simply right click the shortcut, click properties, and add the command line parameters on the command line field.

but windows8.1 does not show any way to edit it! what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i was one right click away from the answer.

must right click the shortcut, then go to the actual program shortcut inside the odd panel, and there i get my familiar properties option.

[image]